# How do I resize rows with setRowHeight and resizeRowToContents in PyQt4?

Tags: python, resize, pyqt4, qtableview

I have a small issue with proper resizing of rows in my tableview.
I have a vertical header and no horizontal header.
I tried:

```
self.Popup.table.setModel(notesTableModel(datainput))
self.Popup.table.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
self.Popup.table.verticalHeader().setFixedWidth(200)
for n in xrange(self.Popup.table.model().columnCount()):
    self.Popup.table.setColumnWidth(n,150)
```

And this works fine, but when I try:

```
 for n in xrange(self.Popup.table.model().rowCount()):
     self.Popup.table.setRowHeight(n,100)
```

or

```
for n in xrange(self.Popup.table.model().rowCount()):
     self.Popup.table.resizeRowToContents(n)
```

No row is resized, even if the text exceeds the length of the cell.

How can I force the rows to fit the data?

Comment: It's not clear which direction you expect the row/column to be resized. Are you talking about word-wrapping?

Comment: Yes, exactly; I want the rows to increase height based on the content of the cells in that row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me, both `setRowHeight` and `resizeRowsToContents` work as expected. Here's the test script I used:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, rows, columns):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.table = QtGui.QTableView(self)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        model =  QtGui.QStandardItemModel(rows, columns, self.table)
        self.table.setModel(model)
        text = 'some long item of text that requires word-wrapping'
        for column in range(model.columnCount()):
            self.table.setColumnWidth(column, 150)
            for row in range(model.rowCount()):
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
                model.setItem(row, column, item)
                # self.table.setRowHeight(row, 100)
        self.table.resizeRowsToContents()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window(4, 3)
    window.setGeometry(800, 150, 500, 250)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: The word wrapping works for me, however I can't set the height manually;

Comment: @Mee. What do you mean? Did you try uncommenting the `setRowHeight` line in my script? (You'll also need to comment out the `resizeRowsToContents` line).