# How to print multi rows entry at the same cell of PyQt5 tableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5

How to print multi rows entry at the same cell of PyQt5 tableWidget
(equivalent to that when u pressing Alt+Enter at Excel) so longer line splitting but stays at the same cell.

My question is related to this one [How do I resize rows with setRowHeight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40019022/how-do-i-resize-rows-with-setrowheight-and-resizerowtocontents-in-pyqt4)
but at that questing they are just expanding row width, I want to combine `self.table.resizeRowsToContents()` with splitting the line.

for example I have a list: `list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']`

and I want to split each component of the list to the new line of the same cell

so instead of `A, B, C`  it will be

```
A,
B,
C
```

[image]

```
column = 1
datalist = [['A'],['B'],['C']]
for numRows in range(1,10):
    self.tableWidget.setItem(numRows, column, QTableWidgetItem(str(datalist)))
```

[image]

Comment: How is the list data inserted into the table widget? Is it added by code? Do those cells need to be editable?

Comment: @musicamante just edited the question with the sample. Insert goes in cycle by setItem. Not editable (it's basically append to the same cell) but at tableWidget no such a method as append (

Comment: Uhm. Do you really insert items like that (using a nested list)? Is there a specific reason for that? Do you need it to be like that in your implementation? I'm asking because using nested objects might add more complexity, especially if the object structure is not always consistent.

Comment: @musicamante this is simplified version, but in general there is the list of lists where I'm dumping internal list data to specific column in the emit cycle. so there is not consistent number of elements of the specific cell. That's why I need kinda append for each function

Comment: Well, this could make things a bit more complicated, and I believe you might prefer a QTableView instead of a QTableWidget, or, at least, provide a standardized way of showing the values, since their structure might vary: for example, what should be displayed if the data is something like `[['A'], ['B', 'B2', 'B3'], ['C', 'C2']]`? Should it be "flattened" (with the item showing single lines for `A, B, B2, B3, C, C2`)? Or should it preserve the nested structure (with the first line being `A`, the second `B, B2, B3`, and the third `C, C2`)?

Comment: @musicamante last statement is correct "It should preserve the nested structure (with the first line being A, the second B, B2, B3, and the third C, C2) "
if there only one element at nested  list then there's no jump to the second line of the cell
Just add another image to the question

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution is to use an item delegate, and implement both its [`sizeHint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#sizeHint) and [`paint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#paint) methods.

Then, it's just a matter of implementation:

```
class ListDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        hint = super().sizeHint(option, index)
        try:
            # try to make the string value a python object
            values = eval(index.data())
            if isinstance(values, (tuple, list)) and len(values):
                # let's assume that a blank item always has a "blank" line at least
                baseHeight = super().sizeHint(option, QtCore.QModelIndex()).height()
                # and add more line height if required
                hint.setHeight(baseHeight + option.fontMetrics.height() * (len(values) - 1))
        except:
            pass
        return hint

    def paint(self, qp, option, index):
        try:
            values = eval(index.data())
            assert isinstance(values, (tuple, list)) and len(values)
            style = option.widget.style()
            # draw a default blank item
            style.drawControl(style.CE_ItemViewItem, option, qp, option.widget)
            enabled = option.widget.isEnabled() and bool(index.data(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled))
            # then overlay its contents
            style.drawItemText(qp, option.rect, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, option.palette, enabled, 
                '\n'.join(', '.join(v) for v in values))
        except:
            # no data or no list contents
            super().paint(qp, option, index)

class TableTest(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(10, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.tableWidget.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, ListDelegate())

        column = 1
        dataList = iter(tuple(ascii_uppercase) + tuple(u + l for u, l in zip(ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase)))
        for numRows in range(1,10):
            try:
                data = [[next(dataList)]]
                for _ in range(randrange(1, 5)):
                    if choice([0, 1, 2]):
                        data[-1].append(next(dataList))
                    else:
                        data.append([next(dataList)])
                self.tableWidget.setItem(numRows, column, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
            except:
                pass

        self.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents()
        self.resize(self.width(), 400)
```

Comment: for a first look it's super overcomplicated, I need to  deep dive to understand does it even make sense. 
What is the reason for `dataList ` variable?

Comment: @NickPV it's just for the sake of the example. Run it and you'll probably understand it.